# Using Liferay as a SSO provider for another application

Tags: tomcat, deployment, liferay, single-sign-on

I understand I am in a very non-standard situation that probably violates every Liferay best practice on earth, but bear with me.

I have an independent web application, contained in its own .war, that i somehow managed to deploy on the same Tomcat that has my bundled Liferay 6.1.0 installation, so that i got Liferay to respond to its own context path (`/wise`) and my other application respond to its own, `/wip-reports`.

What I need to do now is to have my preexistent web application check if requests are coming from a user that has logged in to Liferay or not, basically having Liferay act as a SSO provider for my application.

I added a `liferay-plugin-package.xml` to my application's `WEB-INF` to have Liferay believe it's a portlet, but I still don't know how (if) I can have Liferay tell my other application's servlets if requests are coming from a user that has signed on or not.

I was told to add Liferay's `InvokerFilter` to my application's `web.xml`, but even after doing so I had no success, and looking at the `InvokerFilter` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.liferay.portal/portal-service/6.1.0/com/liferay/portal/kernel/servlet/filters/invoker/InvokerFilter.java) I don't see how this could possibly have been of any help.

Any (preferably simple) ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Liferay 6.1 EE comes with a SAML provider built in
https://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/getting-started-with-liferay-saml-2-0-identity-provider

For CE editions, you're on your own, but I guess that with some clever liferay services one could accomplish a lot. YOu could get some hints [from here](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/14783822) on the liferay forum.

Good luck